# POST request body is empty on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make an AJAX request from the client side javascript using XMLHttpRequest. Following is the code for it:

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit=function(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var text = document.getElementById('myinput').value;
    console.log(text);
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200){
            location.reload();
        }
    };
    http.open('POST','/todo',true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var obj = {
        item:text
    };
    http.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

This works fine without anny errors. However, on the server side, when I try to log the request body to the console, it shows as an empty object. Can someone help me with this? Following is the server side code for handling the post request:

```
app.post('/todo',urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body); // This logs an empty object to the console!
    newItem = Todo(req.body);
    newItem.save(function(err,data){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: add bodyparser node module

Comment: Abhishek, I have already added the body-parser module.

Comment: it should be above all the routes. can you paste code?

Comment: What does urlencodedParser does? Can you try without it?

Comment: Abhishek, I don't think there's a problem with the body-parser module. The app worked fine when I made an AJAX request using JQuery. When I switched to XMLHttpRequest API, it stopped working.

Comment: Suleyman, urlencodedparser is a middleware that allows me to access the req.body attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON encoding and URL encoding are different.

If you wish to send the data with JSON encoding, then you must receive it with the appropriate middleware:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.post('/todo', bodyParser.json(), function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body); // This logs an empty object to the console!
    newItem = Todo(req.body);
    newItem.save(function(err,data){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

It most likely worked with jQuery because urlencoding is default behavior for `$.post`.